# How to make an opaque background?

Tags: flutter, dart

So basically I am trying to create a container which is just slightly opaque. I am use the `.withOpacity(...);` method however I am not getting the exact look I want. The look I'm going for is the in Apple Music:

Light mode:
[image]

Dark mode:
[image]

Its like its not opaque but its like glass, foggy glass.

Edit: Here is what I have so far:

```
Widget opaqueContainer(BuildContext context) {
  final bool themeIsDark = true; // will use state manager here when implemented.
  return Container(
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    color: themeIsDark ? Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7) : Colors.white.withOpacity(0.85),
    child: IconButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      icon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.phone, color: primary),
    ),
  );
}
```

How can I create this color?

Comment: Do post the existing code you have at the moment. It would take more than color to create this effect and its hard to answer what exactly needs to be done without seeing the code :)

Comment: @RohanThacker Alright. Updated. I really don't have much. I honestly thought it was just opacity haha.

Comment: Its a trending design pattern at the moment, "Glassmorphism" do check out more about [here](https://webflow.com/blog/glassmorphism) if you'd like to know more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create the effect above you'd need to use a combination of a `blur` effect along with the color needed, the `blur` effect will give you the foggy glass look and feel.

In flutter you can blur the area behind the widget by using the `BackdropFilter` widget like below.

```dart
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
// Use ClipRect to contain the effect to the child's size. 
ClipRect(
      child: BackdropFilter(
        filter: ui.ImageFilter.blur(
          sigmaX: 2.5,
          sigmaY: 2.5,
        ),
        child: Container(
          height: 80,
          width: 320,
          color: themeIsDark
              ? Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7)
              : Colors.white.withOpacity(0.85),
          child: Center(
            child: Text("Hello Word"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

This will give you an output like the example below.
[image: An example of a flutter effect in flutter]

*Note: this is a minimal example to display the blue effect not a recreation of the design above*

---

**Docs**

[BackdropFilter Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BackdropFilter-class.html)

[ImageFilter Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ImageFilter-class.html)